# Can I get my Google calendar info into a shareable/printable format?

Tags: google-calendar, export, printing

I want to output certain parts of a calendar to print. The very frustrating thing, though, is that the default print view for GCal only shows the start-time of events, not their duration.. so it's not adequate for demonstrating my availability.  Even the list view is not workable easily because it has these 'event created by' details for every single event and no way to remove that so I waste so much space.

Is there any way to get the info from GCalendar into something else that will give me the control over its output to make it customizable?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your OS choice, Google calendar in apps like Mac OS X's iCal allow for greater detail when printing.

Answer (score 1):

You can export it to excel, google docs (or a printable web page) with [www.gtimereport.com](http://www.gtimereport.com/) and do whatever you like from there.

It's actually for generating time reports but usually it fits quite nicely for other uses too.

(I'm the author)